# Access VBA - SQL Statement using VBA to fill List Box on form using Text Box Combo Boxes Values Where OR

Tags: vba, ms-access

Need some help, examples, and advice

I have 2 tables | tblMAIN  |  tblRECORDS
and One Form | frmFAMILY - data source: tblMAIN

I am trying to create a simple SQL Statement using VBA in access that will 
match records From tblRECORDS that match WHERE text box OR 2 combo box values on the form frmMAIN match and then fill List Box listRECORDS with data And ignore any values if they are 0.

all of the values are numbers but would like to know how to format if i decide to search for text, like, etc.

I would also like to incorporate some If Then Else. Does anyone know a good resource for SQL statements using VBA examples?

This is what I have but it is not working.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim strRecords As String
 strRecords = "Select * FROM tblRECORDS WHERE tblRECORDS.RecordID = [Forms]![frmFAMILY].[txtID] OR tblRECORDS.RecordID2 = [Forms]![frmFAMILY].[cboSpouse1]"
 Me.listRECORDS.RowSource = strRecords
 Me.listRECORDS.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: There are examples all over the web. For the one you posted, remove `ALL` as well as the 2 extra quote marks at end.

Comment: Start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/build-sql-statements-that-include-variables-and-controls

Comment: Hi, Removed ALL and the 2 extra quotes and still not working 

Comment: Tested code and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by adding `OR` instead of `AND`.